# If $f$ is bounded on a neighbourhood of $c$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0$, then show that $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Could someone please explain to me how to prove the following question

If $f$ is bounded on a neighbourhood of $c$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0$, then show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}g(x)f(x)=0$

I was thinking maybe if I am able to prove that being bounded on some neighbourhood of $c$ implies that the limit at $c$ exist then this problem would be trivial 
but my question is "does being bounded on some neighbourhood of $c$ implies that the limit at $c$ exist"?

Answer (score 1):

No, a bounded function may have no limit. But, observe that if $|f(x)| \le M$, then $|f(x) g(x)| \le M|g(x)|$ so that $|g(x) - 0| < \epsilon / M$ implies $|f(x) g(x) - 0| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much man. I did the same thing but I thought I was wrong. I am so happy I got my first proof correct all by myself.